# How do I remote debug over Serial Port or USB with Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, embedded, eclipse-cdt, remote-debugging

I'm working on a device that has an unstable wireless connection and therefore requires a serial cable to debug programs that run on it while the Firmware team works on fixing the wireless connections.  This happens often as new devices tend to be unstable at first.  The problem is I can't seem to find out how to remote debug in Eclipse CDT when using a serial port.  I've been doing some searching online and have found lots of info about remote debugging via SSH, FTP and Telnet.  Although, I can't find anything about debugging through the serial port.  I was able to find info on and use a serial terminal in Eclipse but as far as I can tell this doesn't help me debug a program remotely with the serial connection.  I also know that it's possible due to this Eclipse bug:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=257171

Unfortunately that doesn't tell me how to use this new support :(
I also know GDB allows debugging via serial cable, so surely there is a way to do it with the Eclipse debugger.  I was also wondering if there is a way to get the "Remote System Explorer", an Eclipse plugin, to use a serial port as well?  As far as I can tell it doesn't seem to support serial connections.  Is there another plugin like it that does support serial connections?  Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments by the patch it looks like official support is in Eclipse 3.6 (Helios) M7

The supported CDT approach seems to be to use the GDB serial protocol.

http://www.embecosm.com/appnotes/ean4/embecosm-howto-rsp-server-ean4-issue-2.html

Comment: Dear Tim,
Thanks for your reply.  Although, I'm still a bit confused.  The comment about 3.6 M7 is over a year old, and I'm using version 3.6.1.r361.  I must have downloaded this version only a month or two ago.  Shouldn't my version support the new feature and if so how do I use it?

I've also known about GDB for quite some time now, so the issue is not exactly just remote debugging, but remote debugging with the eclipse IDE.  This way we can use a fancy gui to debug with instead of a terminal.  Thanks for the link tho, it will come in handy if we can't get eclipse to work.

Comment: It might be worth trying to get command-line gdb talking to the remote stub first; then you'll know what commands the CDT or other IDE will need to issue to the underlying gdb to set up a session.

Comment: @Chris,  Does that mean that Eclipse doesn't already have a module for remote debugging via serial?  Like I said, I know GDB works fine over the serial.  The goal is to use the Eclipse GUI over the serial.  Both are GDB, but I'm unsure how to configure Eclipse to get it to work over the serial.  I apologize if my question was unclear.

Comment: I don't know... with another IDE I ended up having to write my own wrapper to substitute for the gdb executable and switch some parameters around. If you know how to manually set up a session, you should be able to configure eclipse to customize the gdb launch command if there's no official support.

Comment: @Chris,  I see.  Thanks for your help.  Considering that I've not been able to find another solution ...perhaps creating my own Eclipse Module is the best option.  I suppose the point of the question is to find out if there is another ... easier way.  Thank you for all you help.